# Is there a shorter way to align text left and right then i did?

Tags: html, css

first sorry for my english, i know it's bad but i really try.

I have a header where i want to place the "title" on the left side and a a symbol with a text on the right side.

I want to make this whole thing "shorter", it looks like there are to many divs but when i do it in a different way it doesn't work for me somehow.
"123" should be next to the symbol "navbutton".

HTML

```
<div>
      <div class=fl>
        <span class=apptitle>JustFaq.it</span>
      </div>
      <div class=tar>
        <span id=loadtime>123</span>
        <span class=navbutton>&#9776;</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.fl {
  float: left
}

.tar {
  text-align: right
}

.apptitle {
  margin-left: 5%
}

.navbutton {
  margin-right: .5%;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qyo6gwv5/3/

Comment: There are multiple different ways to get that positioning. However, any answer to your question would be opinionated and this type of questions are discouraged here.

Comment: Off topic, but it's amazing how often after an apologetical "sorry for my English" follow posts that are near perfect, at least perfectly understandable and oftentimes better than what even some native speakers might produce. :)

Comment: @Connum I think it's more about the idea of a `bare-bone` (spartan) mock-up with a good vibe. I knew it was off-topic but just couldn't resist. See answer below :) (the hidden snippet. I hide it as it's double off-topic: off-topic answer to off-topic question. Hey, does that make it on-topic? :))

Comment: @andrei-gheorghiu Haha, I meant my own comment to be off topic, not the question (which might arguably be considered to be), but great what you came up with! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simplify both `html` and `CSS`

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <span>JustFaq.it</span>
  <span>&#9776;</span>
</header>
```

---

Even if *is* opinionated, I admit I was instantly sold to the idea of making a bare-bone layout, while trying to keep it smooth, with a good vibe.
I took the liberty to play and push it a bit further. Hope you don't mind:

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
header > * {
  padding: 8px;
}
nav {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
nav toggle {
  min-width: 2rem;
  min-height: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: background-color .3s linear;
}
nav:hover toggle {
  background-color: #444;
  color: white;
}
nav .subnav {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #444;
  color: white;
  top: 100%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  transition:  transform .3s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
}
.subnav > * {
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.12);
  transition: background-color .2s linear;
}
.subnav > *:hover {
  background-color: #3c3c3c;
}

nav:hover .subnav {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <span>JustFaq.it</span>
  <nav>
    <toggle>&#9776;</toggle>
    <div class="subnav">
      <div>option 1</div>
      <div>option 2</div>
      <div>option 3</div>
      <div>option 4</div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, using flexbox:

```
.head1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2qfzsf6t/1/

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is:

```css
.fl {
  display: inline-block;
}
.tar {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="head1">
      <div class="fl">
        <span class="apptitle">JustFaq.it</span>
      </div>
      <div class="tar">
        <span id="loadtime">Text</span>
        <span class="navbutton">&#9776;</span>
      </div>
</div>
```

Pay attention to the quotes around HTML attributes. You are missing quotes around classes and IDs.

Consider to replace `<div class=head1>` with HTML5's `<header>` element instead. And sure you may want to get rid or non-necessary tags here and simplify it to:

```html
<header>
  <h1 class="apptitle">JustFaq.it</h1>
  <span class="navbutton">&#9776;</span>
</header>
```